# Should I label every frames from videos that I want to train my model to?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I want to build a model that can detect the chords that are being played on a guitar. Now I am planning to build it using YOLOv8 and annotate the frames using CVAT. Now I also have seen the tutorials on how you can train your own model using YOLOv8 and I also understand how object detection works(still studying on that field so not really) but I have never trained one using a custom dataset. Should I label every single frame that contains the important bits(see attached image) on how to play the chords or should I only label some of them that's different enough that also contains the important bits? My thought is that I shouldn't label every frame because it would make the training data too big and make it too hard to run and because it's a video, it will not gather enough information because the difference from frame X to frame X+1 is very little. Or maybe I should do something else? I am looking for guidance on how to proceed. Thanks in advance <3

[The following image is the labeling process, I choose to label it from the nut(0th fret) up to the octave which is the 12th fret because that's where the chords that I want to detect are located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uQfx.png)